# Python y Apache: mod_fcgid no funciona

Tags: python, apache, cgi

Recientemente descargué el módulo de apache **mod_fcgid.so** y lo copié en la carpeta **modules**. En **httpd.conf** agrego lo siguiente:

**LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so**: para cargar el módulo.

**addHandler fcgid-script .py**: para que los archivos .py se carguen a traves de fcgid.

**fcgidWrapper "C:/Python310/python.exe"**: para indicarle a fcgid donde se encuentra el intérprete de Python.

Y comenté la línea que carga **mod_cgi** (el CGI que viene por defecto) para que no haya conflictos.

Cuando recargo Apache no me da ningún error. Todo bien hasta ahora. Pero cuando llamo a Fetch de Javascript apuntando a un archivo .py (lo cual funciona perfectamente con el CGI normal), me da error. Esto dice los logs de apache: **End of script output before headers: Prueba.py, referer: https://127.0.0.1/**. Parece que hay algún problema con los headers, pero como he dicho, con CGI funciona todo a la perfección, pero con fcgid falla.

Algo tan simple como esto da error:

```
#!C:/Python310/python
print ('Content-type: text/plain')
print ()

print ('Probando')
```

Probé quitando el **print ()**, agregando **\n\n** después de **text/plain**, quitando el **Content-type**, quitando la primera linea (el comentario que indica la ubicación del intérprete). Ya no sé que mas probar.

**NOTA**: todo quiero hacerlo con python puro. Nada de frameworks como Django o Flask.

Comment: proba con el python en modo unbuffered `FCGIWrapper "c:/Python/python.exe -u" .py`

Comment: Acabo de probar y nada. Me da un 500 Internal Server Error y en los logs de Apache sigue saliendo **End of script output before headers**.

Comment: Recuerdo que con CGI me daba igual un error 500 hasta que le ponia el comentario del interprete, los headers y el print vacio del salto de linea que separa los headers del resto del codigo. Parece que con fcgid no funciona. Segun los logs es un problema de los headers.

Comment: `print('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')` y despues los headers? ref https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6

Comment: Probe y nada. ¿Es posible ejecutar Python con fcgid? Acabo de probar con PHP y funciona perfecto. Python funciona con el CGI normal, pero no con fcgid

Comment: sin framework ni idea, fijate si esta config te sirve https://webpy.org/install#apachefastcgi o de ultima le pispeas el code al [source](https://github.com/webpy/webpy)

Comment: Mi objetivo es ejecutar python con mayor velocidad, ya que CGI es muy lento. Estaba usando websockets y son perfectos, pero es obligatorio emplear **wss** para ussarlo en la red local, y mi certificado ssl es autofirmado. Los clientes tenian que entrar a las direccion del websocket por http, lo cual logicamente da error por ser 2 protocolos diferentes. Pero de esta forma salia el aviso de excepcion de seguridad del navegador, aceptaban la excepcion y el websocket se conectaba, de lo contrario no podia conectarse porque el navegador no confiaba en el ssl del websocket. Muy rapido pero muy sucio

Comment: en modo cgi apache levanta el proceso del interprete le pasa la data de la peticion y espera q termine, cada peticion es un nuevo proceso, por eso es "lento". 
fastcgi levanta y reutiliza un proceso/interprete que se encarga de manejar los scripts. esa comunicacion es via tcp o sockets unix, php funciona pq en modo fastcgi el interprete es php-fpm. 
python al parecer no trae esa funcion de manera nativa de ahi que te diga que el proceso terminó sin enviar ni siquiera headers.

Comment: O sea Python y FastCGI son incompatibles. Yo pudiera quedarme facilmente con wsgi o con websockets (se trabajar con ellos y ambos son muy rapidos, aunque websockets es el mas veloz), pero para eso necesito un certificado ssl que no este autofirmado. Y no tengo forma de conseguir uno, ni siquiera de Let's Encrypt